# SQL query to return rows when values from columns do not match

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a query that will return rows when one column doesn't match another column.  For example.  Column A is 12.  Column B is 15.  I would want both results returned.  If Column A is 12  and column B is 12, no results.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: If A is 12 and B is null, should that row be returned or not?

Answer (score 0):

The most simple filter will do:

```
select * from my_table where a <> b
```